# How to give a canvas max space and place left (scrollable) and right "menu" divs on it?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have prepared a complete and simple [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/y0dtef9b/) for my question.

My [word game](https://wordsbyfarber.com) currently uses an HTML table for laying out HTML canvas and jQuery UI buttons.

I would like to get rid of the HTML table and instead use HTML div elements, which I have written out in the red/yellow boxes with arrows at the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I would like to have the following structure of the div elements:

```
- fullDiv (should occupy 100% width and height of browser window)
-- hintDiv (100% width, min height, visible on top)
-- mainDiv (100% width, max height)
--- gameDiv (100% width, max height)
---- myCanvas (100% width, max height)
-- leftDiv (min width, same height as mainDiv, scrollable) <- relative position
-- rightDiv (min width, same height as mainDiv) <- relative position
-- totalDiv (100% width, min height, visible on bottom)
```

The idea is to give `myCanvas` as much space as possible and place `leftDiv` and `rightDiv` as kind of "menus" of both sides of it. The `leftDiv` would be a navigational menu with a scrollable list of games and have the same max possible height as `myCanvas` and `rightDiv`.

So I have tried the following code -

```js
$(function () {
  $(':button').button();
  $('#fullCheck').checkboxradio();

  var gamesMenu = $('#gamesMenu').menu({
    items: '> :not(.ui-widget-header)'
  });

  for (var game = 1; game <= 50; game++) {
    gamesMenu.append('<LI VALUE="' + game + '">GAME ' + game + '</LI>');
  }
    gamesMenu.menu('refresh');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#fullDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFF;
}

#hintDiv,
#totalDiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#mainDiv,
#gameDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#myCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px red dotted;
  background: #CCF;
}

#leftDiv {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  text-align: center;
  background: #FCC;
}

#rightDiv {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  text-align: center;
  background: #CFC;
}

#gamesMenu {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#hintDiv {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullDiv">
  <div id="hintDiv">Hint</div>
  <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="gameDiv">
      <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div id="leftDiv">
      <button id="newBtn">New game</button>
      <ul id="gamesMenu"></ul>
    </div>

    <div id="rightDiv">
      <input id="fullCheck" type="checkbox">
      <label for="fullCheck">Full screen</label><br>
      <button id="recallBtn">Recall</button><br>
      <button id="shuffleBtn">Shuffle</button><br>
      <button id="swapBtn">Swap</button><br>
      <button id="skipBtn">Skip</button><br>
      <button id="resignBtn">Resign</button><br>
      <button id="pileBtn">Pile</button><br>
      <button id="movesBtn">Moves history</button><br>
      <button id="shareBtn">Share</button><br>
      <button id="playBtn">Play</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="totalDiv">Total</div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

However, my screen is totally messed up now:

- The elements `myCanvas`, `leftDiv` and `rightDiv` are placed after each other instead of `leftDiv`/`rightDiv` covering `myCanvas` on its both sides
- `myCanvas` occupies the whole browser window, pushing `hintDiv`/`totalDiv` out of screen
- `gamesMenu` is displayed in its whole glory instead of being scrollable

[image: screenshot]

**UPDATE:**

Here the solution by Derek (thank you!)

```js
$(function () {
  $(':button').button();
  $('#fullCheck').checkboxradio();

  var gamesMenu = $('#gamesMenu').menu({
    items: '> :not(.ui-widget-header)'
  });

  for (var game = 1; game <= 50; game++) {
    gamesMenu.append('<LI VALUE="' + game + '">GAME ' + game + '</LI>');
  }

    gamesMenu.menu('refresh');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#fullDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#hintDiv,
#totalDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}

#leftDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #FCC;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#gamesMenu {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gameDiv {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#myCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px red dotted;
  background: #CCF;
}

#rightDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #CFC;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#hintDiv {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullDiv">
  <div id="hintDiv">Hint</div>
  <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="leftDiv">
      <button id="newBtn">New game</button>
      <ul id="gamesMenu"></ul>
    </div>

    <div id="gameDiv">
      <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div id="rightDiv">
      <input id="fullCheck" type="checkbox">
      <label for="fullCheck">Full screen</label><br>
      <button id="recallBtn">Recall</button><br>
      <button id="shuffleBtn">Shuffle</button><br>
      <button id="swapBtn">Swap</button><br>
      <button id="skipBtn">Skip</button><br>
      <button id="resignBtn">Resign</button><br>
      <button id="pileBtn">Pile</button><br>
      <button id="movesBtn">Moves history</button><br>
      <button id="shareBtn">Share</button><br>
      <button id="playBtn">Play</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="totalDiv">Total</div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

For some reason jQuery UI menu is not hoverable (eventhough in the [official demo](https://jqueryui.com/menu/#categories) it is)...

My workaround sofar is (to at least see the selected item):

```
li.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}

var gamesMenu = $('#gamesMenu').menu({
  items: '> :not(.ui-widget-header)',
  select: function(ev, ui) {
    ui.item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished using [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) layout.

- Make the `#fullDiv` to use `flex` layout with `flex-direction: column` so that it can be aligned on columns.
- Set `flex: 1 1 auto` to `#mainDiv` so that it can take the space except the `#hintDiv` and `#totalDiv` on `#fullDiv`.
- Set `#mainDiv` to `flex` layout too with `justify-content: space-between`. You will know about that on [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- Due to that guide, exchange the `#leftDiv` and `#gameDiv`.
- On `#gameDiv`, I have updated the canvas width and height as `calc(100% - 8px)` because the border size will be added to the real canvas size. So now, canvas border width is 4px so the canvas width will be `(100% - 8px) + 8px(border size) = 100%`.

```js
/*$(function () {
  $(':button').button();
  $('#fullCheck').checkboxradio();

  var gamesMenu = $('#gamesMenu').menu({
    items: '> :not(.ui-widget-header)'
  });

  for (var game = 1; game <= 50; game++) {
    gamesMenu.append('<LI VALUE="' + game + '">GAME ' + game + '</LI>');
  }
});*/
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#fullDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFF;
}

#hintDiv,
#totalDiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#myCanvas {
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  border: 4px red dotted;
  background: #CCF;
}

#leftDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #FCC;
}

#rightDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #CFC;
}

#gamesMenu {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#publishBtn {
  max-width: 200px;
}

#timer1,
#timer2 {
  color: red;
}

#hintDiv {
  font-style: italic;
}


/*** Additional Codes ***/
#fullDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#mainDiv {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#gameDiv {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullDiv">
  <div id="hintDiv">Hint</div>
  <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="leftDiv">
      <button id="newBtn">New game</button>
      <ul id="gamesMenu"></ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="gameDiv">
      <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div id="rightDiv">
      <input id="fullCheck" type="checkbox">
      <label for="fullCheck">Full screen</label><br>
      <button id="recallBtn">Recall</button><br>
      <button id="shuffleBtn">Shuffle</button><br>
      <button id="swapBtn">Swap</button><br>
      <button id="skipBtn">Skip</button><br>
      <button id="resignBtn">Resign</button><br>
      <button id="pileBtn">Pile</button><br>
      <button id="movesBtn">Moves history</button><br>
      <button id="shareBtn">Share</button><br>
      <button id="playBtn">Play</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="totalDiv">Total</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Derek. I have tried your code in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/hnvL8you/) and the `gamesMenu` is too high, how to make it scroll instead?

Comment: Make `#leftDiv` as flex layout so. `#leftDiv { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }` and add this to `#gamesMenu`. `#gamesMenu { flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto; }`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help: here the new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/7r8tjxbo/) with your code added at the bottom of CSS

Comment: Set `overflow:hidden` on `#mainDiv` then it will work.

Comment: Thank you, the layout is perfect now. The only problem is that it breaks the jQuery menu - it is no more hoverable (the "GAME X" entries do not change color when mouse is over them).

Comment: I think that's not related to the layout... Maybe the other problem.